# Graphical solution to equation with Bessel functions in Python

Tags: python, plot, sympy

I would like to plot solutions of:

J1(x)/(x*J0(x))+K1(y)/(y*K0(y))=0

using Python

If `plot_implicit` from `sympy` worked with Bessel functions in this way:

`plot_implicit(Eq(besselj(1,x)/(x*besselj(0,x))+besselk(1,y)/(y*besselk(0,y))))`

something like this would be what I want. But it didn't work for me - probably `plot_implicit` can't accept `besselj` and `besselk` from `mpmath` (at least not in such trivial way).

How can I do it  correctly?

EDIT In case the above is confusing. Calling `besselj` and `besselk` didn't work because I used `mpmath` version of them, there exists `sympy` version of them which can be used.
In the above version I am also missing `, 0` as was pointed out by tel.

Comment: Are you missing a `0` at the end of the call to `Eq`?

Comment: @tel Indeed, thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually can use Sympy and `plot_implicit` to get what you want. You just have to use the versions of the Bessel funcs supplied by Sympy itself. However, `plot_implicit` does seem to struggle with this particular eq:

```
import sympy as sym
x,y = sym.symbols('x y')

sym.plot_implicit(sym.Eq(sym.besselj(1,x)/(x*sym.besselj(0,x))+sym.besselk(1,y)/(y*sym.besselk(0,y)), 0), adaptive=False, points=100)
```

Output:

[image]

I also got a warning:

```
/Users/tel/git/sympy/sympy/plotting/experimental_lambdify.py:165: UserWarning: The evaluation of the expression is problematic. We are trying a failback method that may still work. Please report this as a bug.
  warnings.warn('The evaluation of the expression is'
```

You can increase the accuracy of the result by increasing the value of the `points` arg in the call to `implicit_plot`. Be warned that if you increase it a lot it might take a long time (like until the sun burns out) to compute.